# Deriving COM interfaces in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interface, com

Due to company constraints out of my control, I have the following scenario:

A COM library that defines the following interface (no CoClass, just the interface):

```
[
    object,
    uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IService Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
IService : IDispatch
{
  HRESULT DoSomething();
}

[
    object,
    uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IProvider Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
IServiceProvider : IDispatch
{
  HRESULT Init( IDispatch *sink, VARIANT_BOOL * result );
  HRESULT GetService( LONG serviceIndicator, IService ** result );
};


[
    uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx),
    version(1.0),
]
library ServiceLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

   interface IService;
   interface IServiceProvider;
};
```

I have a COM (written w/ C++) that implements both interfaces and provides our application(s) with said service.  All is fine, I think.

I'm trying to build a new `IProvider` and `IService` in .NET (C#).

I've built a Primary Interop Assembly for the COM library, and implemented the following C#:

```
[ComVisible( true )]
[Guid( "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )]
public interface INewService : IService
{
   //  adds a couple new properties
}

[ComVisible( true )]
[Guid( "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )]
public class NewService : INewService
{
   //  implement interface
}

[ComVisible( true )]
[Guid( "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )]
public interface INewProvider : IServiceProvider
{
   //  adds nothing, just implements
}

[ComVisible( true )]
[Guid( "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" )]
public class NewProvider : INewProvider
{
   //  implement interface
}
```

When I attempt to slip this into the existing runtime, I am able to create the `NewProvider` object from COM (C++), and `QueryInterface` for IServiceProvider. When I attempt to call a method on the IServiceProvider, a `System.ExecutionEngineException` is thrown.

The only other thing I can find, is by looking at the .tlh files created by the #import, shows the legacy COM IExistingProvider class correctly shows that it is derived from IServiceProvider. However the .NET class shows a base of IDispatch.  I'm not sure if this a sign, indication, helpful, something else.

Comment: When you say you've "built" a Primary Interop Assembly, do you mean from scratch?Wasn't it possible just to add the COM library as a reference?

Comment: I built the PIA from the TLBIMP.exe.  Would you like to see an example command line for it?

I used TLBIMP, creating my own Interop.Services.dll, then reference that.

I recently aquired ".NET and COM - The Complete Interoperability Guide".

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't import the library directly into Visual Studio?Or aren't you using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a problem with the name *IServiceProvider*.  Check that you haven't already imported an interface with the same name.

When I create an COM Interface library using your IDL, and then try to import it from another client, I get the warning:

```
Warning 65  warning C4192: automatically excluding 'IServiceProvider' while importing type library 'ServiceLibrary.dll'
```

Otherwise, you can try renaming it to IServiceProvider2.  That's what I did, and everything works fine.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

If this code runs properly on your machine (it works perfectly on mine) then the problem could be in your implementation.

IDL:

```
import "oaidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(9219CC5B-31CC-4868-A1DE-E18300F73C43),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IService Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IService : IDispatch
{
  HRESULT DoSomething(void);
}

[
    object,
    uuid(9219CC5B-31CC-4868-A1DE-E18300F73C44),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IProvider Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IServiceProvider2 : IDispatch
{
  HRESULT Init( IDispatch *sink, VARIANT_BOOL * result );
  HRESULT GetService( LONG serviceIndicator, IService ** result );
};

[
    uuid(9219CC5B-31CC-4868-A1DE-E18300F73C45),
    version(1.0),
]
library ServiceLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    interface IService;
    interface IServiceProvider2;
};
```

C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ServiceLibrary;
using IServiceProvider=ServiceLibrary.IServiceProvider2;

namespace COMInterfaceTester
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2B9D06B9-EB59-435e-B3FF-B891C63108B2")]
    public interface INewService : IService
    {
        string ServiceName { get; }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2B9D06B9-EB59-435e-B3FF-B891C63108B3")]
    public class NewService : INewService
    {
        public string _name;

        public NewService(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        //  implement interface
        #region IService Members

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NewService.DoSomething");
        }

        #endregion

        public string ServiceName
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2B9D06B9-EB59-435e-B3FF-B891C63108B4")]
    public interface INewProvider : IServiceProvider
    {
        //  adds nothing, just implements
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2B9D06B9-EB59-435e-B3FF-B891C63108B5")]
    public class NewProvider : INewProvider
    {
        //  implement interface
        public void Init(object sink, ref bool result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NewProvider.Init");
        }

        public void GetService(int serviceIndicator, ref IService result)
        {
            result = new NewService("FooBar");
            MessageBox.Show("NewProvider.GetService");
        }
    }
}
```

C++ Client:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#import "COMInterfaceTester.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
#import "ServiceLibrary.dll" raw_interfaces_only

using std::cout;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);   //Initialize all COM Components
    COMInterfaceTester::INewProviderPtr pNewProvider(__uuidof(COMInterfaceTester::NewProvider));
    ServiceLibrary::IServiceProvider2 *pNewProviderPtr;

    HRESULT hr = pNewProvider.QueryInterface(__uuidof(ServiceLibrary::IServiceProvider2), (void**)&pNewProviderPtr);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {       
        VARIANT_BOOL result = VARIANT_FALSE;
        int *p = NULL;

        hr = pNewProviderPtr->Init((IDispatch*)p, &result);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Failed to call Init";
        }

        ServiceLibrary::IService *pService = NULL;
        hr = pNewProviderPtr->GetService(0, &pService);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Failed to call GetService";
        }
        else
        {
            COMInterfaceTester::INewService* pNewService = NULL;
            hr = pService->QueryInterface(__uuidof(COMInterfaceTester::INewService), (void**)&pNewService);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CComBSTR serviceName;
                pNewService->get_ServiceName(&serviceName); 

                if (serviceName == "FooBar")
                {
                    pService->DoSomething();
                }
                else
                    cout << "Unexpected service";

                pNewService->Release();

            }

            pService->Release();
        }

        pNewProviderPtr->Release();
    }
    else
        cout << "Failed to query for IServiceProvider2";

    pNewProvider.Release();
    CoUninitialize ();   //DeInitialize all COM Components

}
```

Comment: IServiceProvider is actually defined in the System namespace - that is probably where the naming collisions is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to specify additional attributes on your class to have it marshal correctly. I would look through available attributes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4w8x20h(VS.71).aspx) and maybe look at [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: 1+Crap the codeprojects article should be a freakin book. Its huge!